# Index the first 100 documents only from MongoDB to Elasticsearch

Tags: mongodb, indexing, elasticsearch

im using elasticsearch 1.4.2 and mongodb 2.6.6 And the river plugin for elasticsearch to index from a collection from my database. However, I would like to only index the first 100 documents and not all of them (there are over 30,000)
How can I do that? Here is my index:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_river/mongodb/_meta' -d '{
    "type": "mongodb", 
    "mongodb": { 
    "db": "mydb",
    "collection": "test"
    }, 
    "index": { 
      "name": "mongoindex",
      "type": "mongodb"
    }
}'
```

Comment: What ordering defines "first"?

Comment: @wdberkeley No specific order. I just want a sample from the documents for testing, and I don't have enough memory for all the documents. 100 documents or less should be sufficient. So even if the results are random, it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a weird use case and I don't understand why you want to do this, but you could use the [custom filters](https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/wiki/MongoDB-custom-filter) in MongoDB-River. Set the filter to something like `"{ "to_elastic_search" : true }"`, then stamp 100 documents in MongoDB with that filter:

```
> db.test.find().limit(100).forEach(function(doc) {
    db.test.update({ "_id" : doc._id }, { "$set" : { "to_elastic_search" : true } }) 
} )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm doing this for testing.